# Is this site appropriate to ask questions like "Please analyze all the chords in Song X"?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this site appropriate to ask questions like "Please analyze all the chords in Song X?"  It's not quite clear to me because, chord analysis can be subjective to some extent.  Also, I haven't yet seen any questions like this.

Comment: See also: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/35/do-questions-about-reverse-engineering-compositions-fit-on-this-site

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is similar to homework questions on Stack Overflow – if the asker puts little-to-no effort into the question, it's not helpful and is just a way of getting other people to do your grunt work.

That said, if someone has made substantial effort and just needs a little help (ex: analyzing most of the chords in a song but needing help with just one or two) I think those are fine, especially if people answering can provide helpful tips for how the asker could've figure it out alone.